Ошибка при попытке использовать Windows Forms в библиотеке классов .dll
Мне необходимо создать библиотеку классов, в которой будут использоваться некоторые методы Windows Forms.
Для этого я создал отдельный проект, в котором в каждом классе подключил using System.Windows.Forms. "Forms" подчёркивается красным с ошибкой: "CS0234: The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
Для решения этой проблемы правой кнопкой нажимаю на проект библиотеки классов (.csproj файл), далее Add Project Reference -- далее в поиске выбираю System_Windows_Forms и System.Drawing.dll.
Подключить ссылки не удаётся, возникает ошибка:
MSB3290    Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}". Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.  ClassLibrary    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
Что я делаю не так?

Для того, чтобы всё заработало, нужно создавать проект как библиотеку Windows Forms.
Если уже много наделано, то создайте новый проект библиотеки Windows Forms, а потом посмотрите в csproj, что там нужно изменить.
Там нужно добавить строку <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>.
